# How to find the limit correctly?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, summation

I want to use MMA to find the limit of $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{\sin \frac{\pi}{n}}{n+1}+\frac{\sin \frac{2 \pi}{n}}{n+\frac{1}{2}}+\cdots+\frac{\sin \pi}{n+\frac{1}{n}}\right)$.

```
Limit[Sum[Sin[(i*Pi)/n]/(n + 1/i), {i, 1, n}], n -> Infinity]
```

However, the above code does not get the correct result (the answer is $\frac{2}{\pi}$).

What can I do to get the right results?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The recent command of Mathematica

```
AsymptoticSum[Sin[(i*Pi)/n]/(n + 1/i), {i, 1, n}, {n, Infinity, 1}]
(*2/\[Pi]*)
```

does the job.